# How to build and transpile a react app with instrumented code by istanbul

Tags: reactjs, cypress, istanbul

I am testing a react application using cypress and I want to get the coverage of this test.

I followed some tutorials and I get the coverage correctly. Instrumenting my code using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts-istanbul
When I use this command :

```
npx react-scripts build --coverage
```

the code is built and instrumented so when I use serve my test work and I can get the coverage

The problem is that I am trying to create a job that launches these tests automatically and deploys the app using and nginx. nginx needs the code to be transpiled and the previous command doesn't do it.
So my question is: How can I get my application transpiled with the instrumented code? And have my application deployed with nginx and see the variable __ coverage __?

Comment: why not `jest` which does it for you? Also as far as I know `istanbul` is no longer maintained

Comment: on Cypress documentation what they use is istanbul. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html